# Composite key and where in in squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

How can I write deleteWhere clause in squeryl for entity with composite id?

```
    val list: List[CompositeKey2[Long, Date]] = existing.map(x => x.id).toList
    Schema.entities.deleteWhere(q => q.id in list)

Error:(82, 49) value in is not a member of org.squeryl.dsl.CompositeKey2[Long,java.util.Date]
    Schema.entities.deleteWhere(q => q.id in list)
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a CompositeKey, the `id` method doesn't map directly to a column, so it isn't useful in an `in` clause.  You'll have to structure your where to reference each column that makes up the private key individually.  Without knowing the columns involved it's tough to be more specific, but something like

```
deleteWhere(q => existing.map(e => q.id1 === e.id1 and q.id2 === e.id2).reduce(_ or _))
```